# Having trouble playing audio on the MediaPlayer in Android

Tags: android, audio

New to Android coding here. I'm trying to have the user pick an audio file for the MediaPlayer to play using the "upload" button, and then the MediaPlayer should start playing the file once the user hits "play." Here is my code so far:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        final int ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE = 1;
        File original;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent chooseFile;
                    Intent intent;
                    chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    chooseFile.setType("audio/mpeg");
                    intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);
                }
            });

            Button playButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
            playButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(original.getAbsolutePath());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE: {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        Uri uri = data.getData();
                        original = new File(uri.getPath());
                        String tag = "TAG";
                        Log.d(tag, original.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I can choose the audio file fine, but once I hit play nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After setting your mediaPlayer data source you have to call `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()`

[Media Playback in android](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

Comment: This now returns me with Error (1,-2147483648)

Comment: Yes perhaps because you are declaring the MediaPlayer object inside the onclick callback, try declaring the media player object as class member variable. Take a look here [link](https://gist.github.com/wwrrss/fefc50f60fa93562166e)